# Simple addition problem not working in python

Tags: python

Hey I am new to programming so sorry if I am dumb.

```
print("1st number")
a = input()
print("2nd number")
b = input()
s = (a ++ b) 
print(s)
```

If I put 1 in for both numbers it outputs 11 not 2

Comment: Note that you do not have to `print("prompt")` and then use `input()` as input itself accept prompt as it argument, i.e. you can do `a = input("1st number")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the input string to a number:

```
print("1st number")
a = input()
print("2nd number")
b = input()
s = float(a) + float(b) 
print(s)
```

or int() for an integer casting.